# ArrayList & contains() - case insensitive

Tags: android, arraylist, contacts, case-insensitive

I want the contains() method from ArrayList to be case insensitive.

Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You will have to define your own contains method that will have to iterate among the `ArrayList` and compare the values using the `equalsIgnoreCase` method of the `String` class.

**Edit:** I don't want to be rude, but the question is pretty clear: the guy wants to use the `contains` method. So he can't/should use `toLowerCase` before adding the elements because of too many reasons: for example, he could need the original `String` (not the one that is lowercased). Also, as we are talking about the `contains` method, we are focusing on the elements rather than their indexes (as someone answered some minutes ago).

Answer (score 2):

As @Cristian has said, there is no native method to achieve this.  I thought I'd post the small utility method that I wrote in case it's a useful copy-and-paste:

```
public static boolean ContainsCaseInsensitive(ArrayList<String> searchList, String searchTerm)
{
    for (String item : searchList)
    {
        if (item.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm)) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In Kotlin:

        private fun containsCaseInsensitive(searchList: ArrayList<String>, searchTerm: String): Boolean {
            for (item in searchList) {
                if (item.equals(searchTerm, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }

Comment: Actually, it might be safer to do "searchList.forEach { item ->"  instead of "for (item in searchList) {" in the above as apparently this uses an iterator in a way that can avoid a potential ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this, and I used this workaround with BinarySearch that seems to work:

```
ArrayList al= new ArrayList();
al.Add("Elem1");
al.Add("Elem5");
al.Add("Elem3");
al.Sort();  

if (al.BinarySearch("elem3", new CaseInsensitiveComparer()) > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("Exists");   //this case
else
      MessageBox.Show("Not found");
```